# Extracting Data from DB with WHERE and AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have a table with simulation data for buildings in different years where every year has a single row. The column-headings are

```
id / year / avg_heat_demand / renovation_level / co2_emission / [and some more]
```

I now want to create a table with only the avg_heat_demand for several years as a coulmn, like

```
id / avg_heat_demand_2015 / avg_heat_demand_2025 / avg_heat_demand_2050
```

I know what I want to say but I can't put the SQL-Statements in the right order I guess. I tried for example (I know that this is not the right way but it might explain best what I want to do):

```
CREATE TABLE output_time AS

SELECT id, 
       year, 
       (avg_heat_demand WHERE year = 2015) AS avg_heat_demand_m2_2015, 
       (avg_heat_demand WHERE year = 2050) AS avg_heat_demand_m2_2025, 
       (avg_heat_demand WHERE year = 2050) AS avg_heat_demand_m2_2050 
FROM simulation_output;
```

example data:

```
id | year | avg_heat_demand | etc
----+-----+-----------------+----
11 | 2015 | 55              +
12 | 2015 | 40              +
11 | 2016 | 48              +
12 | 2016 | 49              +
11 | 2025 | 45              +
12 | 2025 | 43              +
11 | 2050 | 50              +
12 | 2050 | 52              +
```

the result I want:

```
id | avg_heat_demand_2015 | avg_heat_demand_2025 | avg_heat_demand_2050 
---+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------
11 | 55                   | 45                   | 50
12 | 40                   | 43                   | 52
```

Comment: what is the function of the column `id` in the second table structure?  Is it really supposed to be shown?

Comment: You probably want to get the `avg_heat_demand` from different rows. From which of these do you want to take `id` and `year`?

Comment: i need the id to connect the table to other tables. it is the building id and there is a row for every year of the same id (id:111 / year:2015 / heat_demand:55 in the next row id:111 / year:2016 / heat_demand:50 ...) . Now i want do have for every id a row with a culumn with the heat_demand of a specific year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know found a soulution with the crosstab function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab('select id, year, avg_heat_demand FROM simulation_output order by 1,2') 
AS final_result(id character varying, avg_heat_demand_m2_2015 double precision, avg_heat_demand_m2_2025 double precision, avg_heat_demand_m2_2050 double precision);
```

as discribed on http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function

Answer (score 1):

Based on this data:

```
 id | avg_heat_demand | year 
----+-----------------+------
 11 |              55 | 2015
 12 |              40 | 2015
 11 |              45 | 2025
 12 |              43 | 2025
 11 |              50 | 2050
 12 |              52 | 2050
(6 Zeilen)
```

Try using subqueries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT AVG(avg_heat_demand) FROM simulation_output WHERE year = 2015) AS avg_2015,
(SELECT AVG(avg_heat_demand) FROM simulation_output WHERE year = 2025) AS avg_2025,
(SELECT AVG(avg_heat_demand) FROM simulation_output WHERE year = 2050) AS avg_2050;

      avg_2015       |      avg_2025       |      avg_2050       
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 47.5000000000000000 | 44.0000000000000000 | 51.0000000000000000
(1 Zeile)
```

If you can afford having the results in multiple rows, try the following query:

```
SELECT year,AVG(avg_heat_demand)
FROM simulation_output
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year

 year |         avg         
------+---------------------
 2015 | 47.5000000000000000
 2025 | 44.0000000000000000
 2050 | 51.0000000000000000
(3 Zeilen)
```

**EDIT**: Based on the OP's edit (different desired output format)

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, 
(SELECT avg_heat_demand FROM simulation_output j WHERE year=2015 AND j.id = i.id) AS avg_heat_demand_2015,
(SELECT avg_heat_demand FROM simulation_output j WHERE year=2025 AND j.id = i.id) AS avg_heat_demand_2025,
(SELECT avg_heat_demand FROM simulation_output j WHERE year=2050 AND j.id = i.id) AS avg_heat_demand_2050
FROM simulation_output i

 id | avg_heat_demand_2015 | avg_heat_demand_2025 | avg_heat_demand_2050 
----+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------
 11 |                   55 |                   45 |                   50
 12 |                   40 |                   43 |                   52
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Doesn't work: ERROR: The result of a subselect is more than one row (SQL state: 21000)  :(

Comment: I can create a table with only one year:
CREATE TABLE simulation_output_2015 AS
SELECT id, avg_heat_demand
FROM simulation_output_cluster_m2
WHERE year = 2015;

Comment: It's hard to know it without sample data. I just edited the answer with a new suggestion

Comment: sure. I fiddle around some more. The subquery with another SELECT was a good hint since I was missing it...

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I want. I don't want to calculate another avg, the data itself is an avg

Comment: @AnniWi just added another query

Comment: depending on the size of your data set + indexes configuration, this might take a while :)

Comment: its quite a big db but its a one time thing so it would be ok if it takes an over night calculation. thanks so far!

Comment: still executing... i think i have to find another solution :(

Comment: Too bad. How big is your table?

Comment: also, can you check if these columns are properly indexed (`id` and `year`)?

Comment: I found an easier solution explained in my answer which works for me best. still: thank you ever so much for your help!!!